# Source for "mini Amidah" after davening

Tags: prayer-book, tefillah-betzibbur

In a number of shuls as well as in a Bet Midrash, I have frequently seen someone who arrives after the services have finished say the beginning of the *Amidah* aloud until after the *Kedusha* (i.e. ending in *Hakel Hakadosh*).

Is there a requirement to hear / join in with *Kedushah*? What is the source for allowing a person to do his own "personal *heicha Kedusha*?

Wouldn't saying the *Kedusha Desidra* (aka *Uva Letziyon*) said near the end of *Shacharit* fulfill the obligation of someone who missed the *Kedusha* during the *Amidah*, anyway? If so, then what would be the need for someone to do this *heicha Kedusha*, or is this a mistake?

Comment: Do you think kedusha desidra needs a Minyan? If not how could you imagine they'd be equivalent

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the scenario here. Davening is done, and somebody gets up to the amud and starts davening again while people mill about?

Comment: @DoubleAA That's a good point, and I believe there is a dispute on that. Have to research that and add that into the "mix".

Comment: @Daniel almost ... It tends to catch people by surprise, most of the time, actually. People in the minyan are ready to leave and someone just starts doing this. I have seen this done in the YU Bet Midrash a few times where people are studying, and suddenly someone does this. In the 1st case, it may actually be Torach detzibbur (people are running to get to work.) In the 2nd case, it may be disrupting someone's learning.

Comment: @DoubleAA SA OC 59:3

Comment: @Ploni - I don't have full access to that source. If there's something relevant, there, please edit my question.

Comment: I find this much more common at mincha than shacharit. At shacharit if you come 15 minutes late you can still catch shmoneh esrei at least with the chazzan; at mincha you've missed it. They generally ask permission from the tzibbur before starting as a matter of courtesy.

Comment: @Ploni That doesn't tell me which side he's assuming.

Comment: "fulfill the obligation of someone who missed the Kedusha during the Amidah" What obligation is this exactly?

Comment: I've never seen that happen before, but it sounds like people are just trying to fulfill their obligation of _tefilah b'tzibur_.