# What is the nature of the obligation to answer to Kedusha?

Tags: mitzvah, minyan, kedusha-prayer

Inspired by [Reaching kedusha during silent shemone esre](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/reaching-kedusha-during-silent-shemone-esre) among many others, and the comment, "'fulfill the obligation of someone who missed the Kedusha during the Amidah' What obligation is this exactly?" by DoubleAA, [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83298/source-for-mini-amidah-after-davening).

Why exactly do we stop and join in with the Kedusha? We have already (presumably) said the bracha of "ata kadosh" in our silent amida, and, strictly speaking, originally, the need for any chazara was [instituted](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Chazarat_HaShatz) only to account for those who would not daven on their own so in a case where all could daven, there would have been no "Kedusha" to say.

This question arises when I am davening with one minyan within earshot of another minyan (which happens at the Kotel among other places). If I am in the middle of my silent amidah and another minyan is saying kedusha, do I have some transcending obligation to stop (as per the requirement discussed in the linked question above) because kedusha is its own obligation or is kedusha related to the repetition of prayer which I am saying as the chazara would supplement my prayer in my minyan, so I would not be exempted of some local obligation by the kedusha from another minyan.

Comment: How is this different from stopping to answer yehei shmeih rabba, barchu, or various other responses

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't know if it is, but since kedusha is part of a chazara for a tefilla which I am saying, I would think that I am somehow more invested in it (potentially).

Comment: http://www.chabad.org/3299224/

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83330/5275

Comment: "There is another [reason] for which the sheliach tzibbur must repeat Shemoneh Esreh — so that Kedushah can be recited by the congregation" from end of 124.4 here http://www.chabad.org/3299223/

Comment: I recommend that you split these questions. One asks about the general reason to respond to Kedusha, and, from what I'm inferring, why Kedusha was instituted to begin with. The other asks for practical halacha on what to do if you are not part of the current minyan that's saying Kedusha.

Comment: @hazoriz I think OP is asking the reverse of what you (Chabbad) answered. I.e., why Kedusha is there.

Comment: Also see http://www.chabad.org/3292066/

Comment: @DanF the issue of why it was instituted is not the focus but the nature of the obligation might depend on the reason it began and would lead into the application in a case of dueling minyanim.

Comment: @DanF https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%94_(%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94)#.D7.94.D7.9E.D7.A7.D7.95.D7.A8_.D7.9C.D7.90.D7.9E.D7.99.D7.A8.D7.AA_.D7.94.D7.A7.D7.93.D7.95.D7.A9.D7.94

Comment: Btw it might be that the obligation is to do it once (a teffila), the second time is less mandatory (and might only be done not to show yourself against it)